# How to configure logger used for "Exception handlers should provide some context and preserve the original exception" issue?

Tags: android, logging, sonarqube

I get this issue:

```
"Exception handlers should provide some context and preserve the original exception"
```

On code like this:

```
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(AnkiDroidApp.TAG, "<actual message here");
}
```

How can I tell to Sonar that our logger isn't Logger, but Log?

Comment: why don't you just also log the cause exception using `Log.e(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr)`

Comment: Way to ask a question that's entirely orthogonal to what i'm asking. ;) It's not my code and i intend to improve error messages, but right now i want to get rid of about 600 errors Sonar reports without needing to s/Log/Logger/ all the files.

Comment: Actually, you're right, that's what Sonar wanted, not the specific name of logger.

Comment: Why do you log an exception and then continue on? That is called "log and swallow". When handling an exception you should re-throw it, or take some compensating action. Don't just continue on blindly as if nothing went wrong...

Comment: @user2800708 Primarily for two reasons: 1. I was, and partly am still, fairly clueless about Java. 2. I was digging through software i had not written myself to clean it up a little and understand it better. If you feel like writing a better answer than i did below that explains these things a little, feel free to do so and i'll change my accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out i misunderstood the complaint of Sonar. It was not expecting a specific name for the logger, but for the code to send both the message AND the exception itself to the logger, like so:

```
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(AnkiDroidApp.TAG, "<actual message here", e);
}
```